# ExtJS takes a very long time to render items

Tags: javascript, performance, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a problem rendering items to a widget I am building. This is how I am doing things:

1. get list of ids (without actual data, just ids and some meta data) from server.
2. loop over list of items (have 90-10 items on average) andadd items using panel.items.add({html: 'some place holder div with id'})
3. loop over ids and make asynchronous calls to server to get actual data, and create some graph and render it inside appropriate placeholder id.

step #3, surprisingly works fine, even though it is the one that loads the most data

step #1 is very fast, it just gets a list of ids from server using a single server call

step #2 is the problem, this is a snippet of code to make it more clear:

```
for (var i=0; i<meta.length; i++) {
   var item = meta[i];
   var divId = "graph" + meta.id  + ..etc;
   panel.items.add({ 
      html: me.getDivHTML(divId, meta, ...);
   });
}
```

this has 2 problems, the first it takes more than a minute to render 90 divs on the screen, and the second, it does not render incrementally, it waits until it is done and shows all divs at once.

I use Chrome. What am I doing wrong? How can I make these divs render faster?

Comment: But you're not rendering 90 divs, you're rendering 90 panels. Also, you should not be modifying the items collection directly. Post a fully working test case, because I can already see a few things seriously wrong with your code.

Comment: Evan is right, also instead of calling items.add(..) in a loop call it once passing in array of item configs.

Comment: Thanks for responses, they all helped to make the rendering faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're getting some weirdness from javascript being single threaded.  Adding 90 items probably isn't the issue, but the constant locking of the thread by the callbacks from the ajax requests would make things a little strange.  I would do one of two things.

1. Preferably, make a function on your server that you can send all those id's too and get an array of all the info you need for those 90 divs!  That way, you can just add a single Ext.container.Container with all the divs in it.  I think that will work best.  I always give my web services an optional "IN" parameter that you can pass an object with field names paired with an array of values that gets translated into an "IN" statement in SQL.  It comes in very useful in situations like this.
2. If that's absolutely not possible, then either build all the information into an array before rendering, or suspend the layouts on the container that it's going into then call doLayout once your done.  See the config and docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-suspendLayout)

Comment: Also, as Evan Trimboli mentioned in his comment on your question, you are adding a lot of panels where you goal is to just add the divs.  You would be much better off adding a less complex component like an Ext.Component, just building the divs and adding them or appending them to the html property, or building a store and using an Ext.view.View to create the markup using a template.

Answer (score 0):

Adding panels to an array first and then adding them at once, as suggested by comments and answer, has helped speed up the rendering.

But I had a different problem, the widget was being rendered multiple times by the caller and so that also added unnecessary wait time.

Now widget renders pretty fast.